# Process Handle Increases using ThreadPool

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a c# application which is refreshed every time interval. I used ThreadPool to do this. Because of this system Handle increases due to that my application is not running long time means after 2 days i am getting System out Of memory Exception. I forcefully releases the Memory but don't have luck to decrease the system Handles. I googled also to decrease Handles but no luck. Can you tell me what i have to do for this. I am using Framework 2.0.

Comment: Without seeing some code, it's hard to say. How are you allocating those handles? Are you freeing those handles when you're done with them? What memory are you forcefully releasing? We can't help you if you don't give us more specific information.

Comment: Maybe do a code audit looking for `IDisposable`s that you aren't disposing...